# Filtrar Resultados en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Muy buenas compañeros, tengo este pequeño problema al querer filtrar resultados, Explico

Al querer filtrar por fecha (todo bien)

Cuando filtro por empleado y sucursal (todo bien)

Cuando filtro por empleado, sucursal y fecha, me arroja todos los resultados sin filtro alguno

Este es mi controlador

```
function permisos(){
        $this->auth->is_logged_in();
        $data['module'] = 'capturista';
        $data['template'] = 'permisos';
        $data['current'] = "permisos";

        $this->load->model('asistencias_model');
        $this->load->model('incidencias_model');

        $data['valor'] = $this->obtenerEstado();
        $capturista = isset( $_POST["capturista1"] ) ? $_POST["capturista1"] : $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $sucursal = isset( $_POST["sucursal1"] ) ? $_POST["sucursal1"] : $this->session->userdata('idSucursal');

        if( isset( $_POST['desde1'] ) && $_POST['desde1'] != "" ){
            $desde = explode("/", $this->input->post("desde1"));                        
            $desde = $desde[2]."-".$desde[0]."-".$desde[1];
        }else{
            //$desde = "";
            $desde = $this->session->userdata('desde1') != NULL ? $this->session->userdata('desde1') : "";
        }

        if( isset( $_POST['hasta1'] ) && $_POST['hasta1'] != "" ){
            $hasta = explode("/", $this->input->post("hasta1"));                        
            $hasta = $hasta[2]."-".$hasta[0]."-".$hasta[1];
        }else{
            //$hasta = "";
            $hasta = $this->session->userdata('hasta1') != NULL ? $this->session->userdata('hasta1') : "";
        }

        $this->load->model('incidencias_model');

        $data['incidencias'] = $this->incidencias_model->getIncidencias($desde, $hasta, $capturista, $sucursal, NULL);
        $data['desde'] = $desde;
        $data['hasta'] = $hasta;

        $this->session->set_userdata(array("desde" => $desde, "hasta" => $hasta, "capturista"=> $capturista,"sucursal" => $sucursal));
        //print_r($data);
        //die();

        $this->load->view('template', $data);       
    }
```

Este es mi modelo

```
function getIncidencias($desde = NULL, $hasta = NULL, $idUser = NULL, $idSucursal = NULL, $idIncidencia = NULL, $capturista = ""){

        $filter=" idIncidencia IS NOT NULL ";
        $this->cleanEspacio($idIncidencia) && $filter.=" AND R.idIncidencia = ".$this->model->cleanSQL($idIncidencia);      
        $this->cleanEspacio($idUser) && $filter.=" AND R.idUsuario = ".$this->model->cleanSQL($idUser);     
        $this->cleanEspacio($desde) && $this->cleanEspacio($hasta) && $filter.=' AND R.permisoDesde BETWEEN "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($desde).' 00:00:00" AND "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($hasta).' 23:59:59" OR R.permisoHasta BETWEEN "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($desde).' 00:00:00" AND "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($hasta).' 23:59:59"';
        $this->cleanEspacio($idSucursal) && $filter.=" AND R.idSucursal = ".$this->model->cleanSQL($idSucursal);

        $sql = "SELECT R.idUsuario, R.idIncidencia, R.tipoIncidencia, P.nombre as nombreSucursal, R.permisoDesde, R.permisoHasta, R.observacion, R.fechaPeticion, R.status, R.motivoStatus, I.first_name AS nombreIncidente, I.last_name AS apellidoIncidente, C.first_name AS nombreCubre, C.last_name AS apellidoCubre FROM incidencias_farmax as R INNER JOIN user as I ON (R.idUsuario = I.user_id) INNER JOIN regiones as P ON (R.idSucursal = P.id)  INNER JOIN user AS C ON (R.idUsuarioCubre = C.user_id) WHERE $filter ORDER BY fechaPeticion DESC ";
        //die($sql);

        return $this->model->query($sql);   
    }
```

Aun sigo sin entender el porque no me realiza bien el filtro, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser que se por que tus BETWEEN deberían ser agrupados AND (R.permisoDesde BETWEEN fecha1 and fecha2 OR R.permisoHasta BETWEEN fecha1 and fecha2 )

ejemplo:

```
$this->cleanEspacio($desde) && $this->cleanEspacio($hasta) && $filter.=' AND (R.permisoDesde BETWEEN "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($desde).' 00:00:00" AND "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($hasta).' 23:59:59" OR R.permisoHasta BETWEEN "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($desde).' 00:00:00" AND "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($hasta).' 23:59:59")';
```

esta otra opción

```
$this->cleanEspacio($desde) && $this->cleanEspacio($hasta) && $filter.=' AND R.permisoDesde <= "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($desde).' 00:00:00" AND R.permisoDesde <="'.$this->model->cleanSQL($hasta).' 23:59:59" AND  R.permisoHasta >= "'.$this->model->cleanSQL($desde).' 00:00:00" AND R.permisoHasta >="'.$this->model->cleanSQL($hasta).' 23:59:59"';
```

Comment: he echo la correccion y aun sigue igual

Comment: prueba con la segunda opción

Comment: La parte de filtrar todo junto es la unica que no esta haciendo lo que debe

Comment: me quede con la primer opcion que pusiste